# Should we add 'shopping questions and product recommendations' to our Help Center dont-ask list?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/4399/99) is currently asking for product recommendations. I've placed the question on hold and wanted to refer the user to our [Help Center page listing the types of questions people shouldn't ask](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I thought product recommendations would be on this list, but I see that the page currently only says:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

**Should we explicitly add '*asking for a shopping or product recommendation*' on this list?**

Note that there already has been [a discussion on banning shopping question on meta on the past](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/99) where it was discussed that we should disallow clear shopping questions, but keep an eye out for questions about sustainable materials that are hard to come by (this one-sentence summary is my own interpretation).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes we should.  We don't have sufficient rules on how to ask those questions in an SE-appropriate way, so they should be off-topic.  If we decide to allow them we'd need specific rules as to how that works.